# React Router - What's the difference between Router and Switch?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to understand the difference between using Router and Switch in React Router.

But I don't understand why using **Switch** in bellow example works:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
     <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            <Route path="/item" component={SocialMediaShare} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But using **Router** throws an error:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
     <BrowserRouter>
        <Router>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            <Route path="/item" component={SocialMediaShare} />
        </Router>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

[image]

Comment: "an error" — **what** error?

Comment: I updated my question with a screenshot of the error in the console.

Comment: Please upload your whole code. Need to read line number 20... This is your code error. This is not related with router and switch.

Comment: My app doesn't have a Router.js. The line 20 is inside Router.js from React itself.

Comment: I updated my answer. There are some issues on your Router components..

Answer (score 22):

In addition to the answers, it should be noted that starting from react-router-dom v6, `<Switch />` has been replaced by `<Routes />`.

Comment: Link to documentation: https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes

Answer (score 7):

There are three primary categories of components in react-router-dom
[image]

**The problem here is you are using `<Router>` component from *react-router-dom* and did not pass all the required props, in this case like *history***

If you want to use `<Router>` component then use one of below code.

```
import { Router, browserHistory } from "react-router";
<Router history={browserHistory} routes={componentRoutes}></Router>
```

**OR**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
    import App from './components/App';
    ReactDOM.render((
       <Router>
           <Route path="/" component={App}/>
       </Router>
    ),
     document.getElementById('root')
   );
```

### Difference Between Switch and Router

The Switch component will work much in the same way as the Router component, meaning we will still have nested Route components that need exact paths

The added functionality of Switch is that **it will only render the first matched  child.** This is really handy when we have nested routes such as the below:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/accounts/new" component={AddForm} />
  <Route path={`/accounts/:accountId`} component={Profile} />
</Switch>
```

[For more details, click here](https://medium.com/@jenniferdobak/react-router-vs-switch-components-2af3a9fc72e)

Answer (score 6):

Switch will render one and only one matching route.  Effectively the first match is rendered even when there are additional matching routes.  Route is not so picky.  It will render all routes that match.  You can use the exact parameter with router to nail it down a little more, but if your SPA is only rendering one component in response to each route, use Switch.  If you need more than one component with a common route prefix, use Router.  There are examples of these differences here:  https://medium.com/@jenniferdobak/react-router-vs-switch-components-2af3a9fc72e.